# multipe group by, count and join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables that look something like this:

#### Table1 Users:

- ID
- Name
- Score

#### Table2 Game:

- ID
- Name
- Fouls

Table 3 Game2

- ID
- Name
- Fouls

What I would like to do is to in Table1, select all users.
Then select all data where Table1.Name = Table2.Name OR Table1.Name = Table3.Name but with higher priority to Table2, so if there is a match Table1.Name = Table2.Name no join from Table 3 will be made.  Then when I've selected the correct that I also would like to count the totalt sum of Score and Fouls.

How is this done in SQL and is it possible?  I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(t1.Score) AS TotalScore,
  SUM(COALESCE(t2.Fouls, t3.Fouls)) AS TotalFouls
FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Name = t1.Name
  LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.Name = NULLIF(t1.Name, t2.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below gets you much of the way there.  Am not sure if you're wanting an aggregate per user or overall, though.

Also - if you're going to have Game3, Game4 etc. then you're best bet is to change your table design rather than having to complicate this (and other) queries further.

```
SELECT      SUM(U.Score) AS Score,
        SUM(Fouls.Fouls) AS Fouls
FROM        dbo.Users U
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT      COALESCE(G.Name, G2.Name) AS Name,
            COALESCE(G.Fouls, G2.Fouls) AS Fouls
    FROM        dbo.Game G
    FULL JOIN   dbo.Game2 G2
    ON      G.Name = G2.Name
) Fouls
ON      U.Name = Fouls.Name
```

Comment: I don't want to aggregate per user. I'm looking for the overall , will this work then? The complexity want go further than this but I get your point.

Comment: @Mikael - try this, see if it give you what you want.  If the aggregations aren't quite right, it'll be a case of GROUP BY to sort it.

Comment: Yes it works but now I need to count the total value of Fouls and Score, how will I have to apply the GROUP BY and COUNT()

Comment: @Mikael - you'd rather use SUM and since you don't want to group by user you can omit the GROUP BY clause.  I've updated my T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can favor the join to Table 2 by specifying in the condition to the join to Table3 `Table2.Name IS NULL`. If you were wanting the total score and fouls on a per player basis here's how you'd do it:

```
SELECT derived_table.Name, SUM(derived_table.Score), SUM(derived_table.Fouls)
FROM (
    SELECT Name = Table1.Name, Score = Table1.Score,
        Fouls = COALESCE(Table2.Fouls, Table3.Fouls)
    FROM Table1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Name = Table1.Name
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Name = Table1.Name
            AND Table2.Name IS NULL
    WHERE Table2.Name IS NOT NULL OR Table3.Name IS NOT NULL
    ) derived_table
GROUP BY derived_table.Name
```

Overall totals:

```
SELECT SUM(derived_table.Score), SUM(derived_table.Fouls)
FROM (
    SELECT Score = Table1.Score,
        Fouls = COALESCE(Table2.Fouls, Table3.Fouls)
    FROM Table1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Name = Table1.Name
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Name = Table1.Name
            AND Table2.Name IS NULL
    WHERE Table2.Name IS NOT NULL OR Table3.Name IS NOT NULL
    ) derived_table
```